# Should I create my object "Random r" before or in my loop

Tags: java, performance, loops, object, random

What I want to know is:
I have a Random object `r` which is currently being created in the while loop.
And I have 3 places where I could create it.

1. Right when the main() starts
2. In the while() loop
3. In the for() loop

Question is: What are the differences? has any of those any advantage or disadvantage.
Is there a difference in performance? Is the randomness affected?

What I know is that I cannot use `r` outside of the loop as it stops existing once the loop terminates. So if I want to use `r` for any other thing it may be required. (right?)

```
    import java.util.*;

    class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numberOfTrue = 0;
        long loopCounter = 0;
        int howManyInts = 20;

        while(numberOfTrue != howManyInts){
            loopCounter += 1;
            numberOfTrue = 0;

            Random r = new Random();

            for(int a = 0; a < howManyInts; a++){       
                if(r.nextBoolean()){
                    numberOfTrue += 1;
                }else{
                   break; 
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("It took " + loopCounter + " loops to get " + howManyInts + " random values which are all even.");
    }
}
```

The program creates "endless" random numbers and if it created `howManyInts` of `0` in a row it terminates.

EDIT1: Changed the code a little as @Peter Lawrey suggested and changing
`if(r.nextInt(2) % 2 == 0)`
to
`if(r.nextBoolean())`
and also renamed some variables to fit the new code

I love to help you help me and I can cope with strong criticism. Don't hold back.

Comment: If you can place it wherever you want, i think the best place is the first option because you don't have to create the random in every interaction

Comment: Note: `r.nextInt(2) % 2 != 0` is the same as `r.nextInt(2) != 0` which is the same as `r.nextBoolean()`

Comment: You can do this without a loop with `areEven = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(r.nextLong())`

Comment: Alternatively you may skip creating `new Random()` altogether, and use `ThreadLocalRandom` instead. It is faster even for single-threaded applications.

Comment: @apangin and how can i use that? ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(2) ??

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2)` or `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean()`

Comment: @apangin Tahnk you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all it should be created outside both of your loops, otherwise it will always allocate a new memory for it instead you can use the same
  If you use it outside, yes you will save memory.
- In terms of performance - it wont b any issue here, now a days we have good cache and RAM so no performance issue
- No the randomness would not affect your code here, every time you create new object of Random class the constructor would increment the seedUniquifier and add the nano seconds from system value

Comment: Note: this is an O(2^n) algo so it doesn't matter how much CPU you have, it will be a problem if n is larger.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should create it outside of the loops because it will be useless object allocation in memory for every iteration and for large data set you could lose a lot of memory for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with nextInt to get many bits at once.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int count;
for(count = 0; ; count++)
    if (rand.nextInt(1 << 20) == 0) // 20 bits which are all zero in a row.
        break;
System.out.println("It took "+count+" loops to get 20 even values in a row");
```

Comment: Could you explain what 1 << 20 exactly does? Or better nextInt(1 << 20 ), because if I think right, it should not give me a row of even values but a row of zeroes (which is an even value). What possible are threre for this? Just 0 and 1?

Comment: I tried using your code and it didn't seem to work for me (at least at higher values). Using 34 instead of 20 didn't yield any realistic result (only if sub 10 loops is realistic for 34 consecutive even numbers in 50% chances...)

Comment: @MrChocodemon The 1 << 20 is a left shift, i.e. 2^^20 obviously an int value limited to 2^^31-1.  Note it will take around 2^^34 attempts to get 34 even/true values in a row which will take a very long time empirically.

Comment: One of my runs for 35 consecutive guesses took 27 seconds. I haven't made any good measurements at this moment, but the longest it took for 35 right now is around 4minutes. If have time to tinker with it a little more I'll let it run 100 times and calculate an average.

Comment: @MrChocodemon is there a reason to measure this empirically when you can just calculate what the chance is? This will take a fraction of a second regardless of the number you use.

Comment: I see what you're getting at.

Comment: @MrChocodemon you have a 1 in 2^^N chance of getting N even/odd/heads/tails in a row.  From this you can get the distribution of possible times taken with some math. You could then randomly select 100 of these and average them.